# MapToStoredProcedures existing procedures ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-code-first

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC website using EF 6 with SQL Server (LocalDB).
I created custom stored procedures for insert, update, delete methods of a table :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Project_Insert
   @LeftBound INT,
   @RightBound INT,
   @Level INT,
   @Name NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @SuggestedAt DATE,
   @SuggestedById INT
AS
BEGIN
...
```

And I would like EF to map those procedures to use them when saving a Project entity in code. So I use MapToStoredProcedures :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().MapToStoredProcedures(p => 
            p.Insert(u => u.HasName("dbo.Project_Insert"))
             .Update(u => u.HasName("dbo.Project_Update"))
             .Delete(u => u.HasName("dbo.Project_Delete")));
```

The problem is, even though I double checked the names of the stored procedure and the model class, the Update-Database method keeps telling me that there are pending changes :

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are     pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.
>   You can use the Add-Migration command to write the pending model changes to a code-based migration.

When I run `Add-Migration Test`, EF creates a migration file with basic Stored Procedures because it thinks it's missing from the DB :

```
CreateStoredProcedure(
"dbo.Project_Insert",
 p => new
 {
     LeftBound = p.Int(),
     RightBound = p.Int(),
     Level = p.Int(),
     Name = p.String(),
     SuggestedAt = p.DateTime(storeType: "date"),
     SuggestedById = p.Int(),
 },
 body:
     @"INSERT [dbo].[Projects]([LeftBound], [RightBound], [Level], [Name], [SuggestedAt], [SuggestedById]) ...
```

My question is : why doesn't EF detect the existing stored procedures and map them to the Project Entity ? Any of you have had this issue before ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code first workflow expects you to do the code first and let it update the database. The workaround is to add an empty migration that will syncronize your manual database changes with the code first model:

```
Add-Migration AddProjectProcs –IgnoreChanges
Update-Database
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#option1